# South does not recognize models when it is a package

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for schema and data migraton for my Django site. I'm happy about using it. One day I converted `models.py` file to `models/__init__py` and put some additional models at `models/something.py`. When I ran `python manage.py schemamigration app --auto`, I got the `Nothing seems to have changed.` message despite of the new classes at `something.py`. If I copied them to the `__init__py` file, South had recognized the new models. I tried to import everything from `something` in the top of `__init__py`, but no change.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's Django design. Django is not picking your models at all, you need to set [`app_label`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) in your model's Meta class.

See ticket on [Automatically discover models within a package without using the `app_label` Meta attribute](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14007).